# How to classify a list of objects having an intersecting list of values

Tags: python, list

I have a list of objects

```
main_streets = [street1, street2, street3 ...]
```

each street has an ordered list of nodes

```
street.nodes = [nd1, nd2, nd3]
```

all streets follow each other in real life (so they share a begining/ending node) but the main_streets list doesn't not represent this reality.

How can i order main_streets?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to classify it as in your title or you want to order it as in your content? And in either case, by what criterion should it be ordered or classified?

Comment: Interesting, but seems like an XY question. You need to do X, you think Y is the solution, so you ask about Y rather than about X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the streets form a single, continuous chain, then you could order them as follows.  First, create the pairs of all connected streets:

```
>>> pairs = [(a, b) for a in main_streets for b in main_streets if a.nodes[-1] == b.nodes[0]]
```

Next, determine which is the first street:

```
>>> seconds = [pair[1] for pair in pairs]
>>> ordered = [s for s in main_streets if s not in seconds]
>>> if len(ordered) > 1:
>>>     raise Exception("Error: There is not one continuous chain.")
```

Now build the chain of streets.

```
>>> unordered = [s for s in main_streets if s not in ordered]
>>> for i in range(len(unordered)):
>>>     for (j, s) in enumerate(unordered):
>>>         if s.nodes[0] == ordered[-1].nodes[-1]:
>>>             ordered.append(unordered.pop(j))
>>>             break
```

If there is a break in the chain (i.e., they aren't all connected), then `unordered` will still contain items after iteration completes.  If you do have multiple chain segments, you can start with the initial `ordered` list and run the last section above for each of those items separately.